# Como hacer una directiva de confirmación antes de guardar o eliminar en angular 2?? Error Cannot read property 'submit'

Tags: angular

mi codigo del html

```
<form class="pt-1" id="enviar" [formGroup]="altaForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">


                <md-form-field class="full-width">
                    <input mdInput type="number" min="1" name="cantidad" placeholder="cantidad" formControlName="cantidad" [(ngModel)]="new.cantidad">
                </md-form-field>

            <div class="card-title-text center">
                <div class="">
                    <span fxFlex></span>
                    <button md-mini-fab type="button" class="mat-primary"  appConfirmacionGuardar [formulario]="enviar"><md-icon>send</md-icon></button>
                </div>
            </div>


        </form>
```

codigo de mi componente formulario

```
 onSubmit(event: Event) {
     event.preventDefault();
      console.log('enviado');
}
```

codigo de mi directiva

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appConfirmacionGuardar]'
})
export class ConfirmacionGuardarDirective {
  constructor() {
  }
  @Input('formulario') miformulario: string;
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick() {
      const confirmed = window.confirm('deseas guardar');
      if (confirmed) {
    (<HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById(this.miformulario)).submit();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar los modulos ya hechos de primeng,

[https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/confirmdialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

[**Get Started!!**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

---

Quedaría algo como lo siguiente

**app.module.ts**:

```
import {ConfirmDialogModule,ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

**confirmacion-guardar-directive.component.html**:

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>
```

**confirmacion-guardar-directive.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmationService } from "primeng/primeng";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmacion-guardar-directive',
  templateUrl: './confirmacion-guardar-directive.component.html'
})
export class ConfirmacionGuardarDirectiveComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private confirmationService: ConfirmationService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Seguro que se desea eliminar?',
      header: 'Confirmation',
      icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
      accept: () => {
        console.log("aceptado");
      },
      reject: () => {
        console.log("rechazado");
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciona pero no sale con los estilos:

Confirmation
Seguro que se desea eliminar?
Yes  No

Comment: Debes importar los estilos. Una opción es en tu archivo **styles.css** importar  `@import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css";
` **y** `@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
` ,otra manera es hacerlo en el **index.html** `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
` **,** `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
` **y** `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
` .Ambos archivos son los que estan a la altura del root

Comment: muchas gracias ahora si funciono